# How to find what was optimized by compiler?

Tags: assembly, gcc, g++, embedded, compiler-optimization

I have a problem with my code. If I compile it with -O0 or -Og it seems to work ok.

But if I use any other flag like -Os, -O1 etc it does not work. How to find what was optimized out by compiler?

Compiler arm-none-eabi-g++ 8.3.1

Source code: https://github.com/bielu000/stm32-libopencm3/tree/uart_not_working_version

I added link to repo, because it would be hard to put the whole code here.
Main code: src/app/src

I think that the problem is in server_run function.

Have a look at screen.

On the left side (it works)->

> optimization:  -O1,
> **attribute**((optimize("-O0"))) void server_run();

On the right side (it doesn't work)->

> optimization:  -O1,
> void server_run();

I don't see any calls to get buffer capacity in optimized (right) version. But why?

Function body

```
extern "C" {
  #include <libopencm3/stm32/usart.h> 
  #include <libopencm3/stm32/gpio.h>
  #include <libopencm3/stm32/rcc.h>
  #include <libopencm3/cm3/nvic.h>
}

#include <server.hpp>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <ring_buffer.hpp>
#include <Os.hpp>
#include <Timer.hpp>
#include <target.h>

static uint8_t w_buffer[1024]; // write buffer
static uint8_t r_buffer[1024]; // read buffer

utils::containers::RingBuffer write_rb{w_buffer, sizeof(w_buffer)};
utils::containers::RingBuffer read_rb{r_buffer, sizeof(r_buffer)};

static void sendData()
{
  if (write_rb.capacity() != 0)
  {
    usart_send(USART1, write_rb.read());
    usart_enable_tx_interrupt(USART1);
  }
  else 
  {
    usart_disable_tx_interrupt(USART1);
  }
}

static void readData()
{
  auto data = usart_recv(USART1);
  read_rb.write(static_cast<uint8_t>(data));
}

void server_init()
{
  //RCC
  rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_USART1);

  //GPIO
  gpio_set_mode(GPIO_BANK_USART1_TX, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_50_MHZ, 
    GPIO_CNF_OUTPUT_ALTFN_PUSHPULL, GPIO_USART1_TX);

  gpio_set_mode(GPIO_BANK_USART1_RX, GPIO_MODE_INPUT, 
    GPIO_CNF_OUTPUT_ALTFN_OPENDRAIN, GPIO_USART1_RX);

  //USART
  usart_set_mode(USART1, USART_MODE_TX_RX);
  usart_set_baudrate(USART1, 9600);
  usart_set_parity(USART1, USART_PARITY_NONE);
  usart_set_databits(USART1, 8);
  usart_set_stopbits(USART1, 1);
  usart_set_flow_control(USART1, USART_FLOWCONTROL_NONE);
  usart_enable_rx_interrupt(USART1);

  //ISR
  nvic_enable_irq(NVIC_USART1_IRQ);
  
  //Enable 
  usart_enable(USART1);
}

void server_run()
{
  while(true)
  {
    size_t xsize = read_rb.capacity();
    if (xsize >= 64)
    {
      while (read_rb.capacity() != 0)
      {
        write_rb.write(read_rb.read());
      }
      sendData();
    }
  }
}

void usart1_isr()
{
  if (usart_get_flag(USART1, USART_FLAG_TXE) != 0) 
  {
    sendData();
  }

  if (usart_get_flag(USART1, USART_FLAG_RXNE) != 0) // when data is ready to read
  {
    readData(); 
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

I changed **xsize** variable type to

> std::atomic<size_t> xsize = read_rb.capacity();

and now it works even with -Os. But why?

[image]

Comment: post an example, sounds like a bug in your code, but without an example we cant help.  You can easily see the output of the compiler to see the differences.

Comment: Also enable all warnings.

Comment: The only answer to such a generic question is a very generic answer: Compare the asm outputs, and/or use a debugger.  Did you maybe forget to use `atomic<T>` for something shared between threads?  [MCU programming - C++ O2 optimization breaks while loop](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/387478)

Comment: Run the unoptimized version through any environment that has `valgrind`.

Comment: You could have Undefined Behavior in your code. Edit the question to include your code.

Comment: You are lucky! Your program has Undefined Behaviour and it reveals itself when compiled with optimization. Think about what would happen if you hadn't found that problem: Your users will find it.

Comment: Try to debug the optimized code and see where it crashes. There's a big probability that the functions/variables involved in the crash are to blame for the bug. Not necessarily, but the best place to start.

Comment: I've added screen with assembly code.

Comment: I changed variable type (that variable which holds buffer capacity) from size_t to std::atomic<size_t> and now it works...

Comment: If I had to guess (and I do because you have not posted the code, and I am not going to follow the off-site link), the "fix" suggests that `RingBuffer::capacity()` is not thread safe and that assigning its return value to an atomic somehow resolves that problem - more by luck than judgement perhaps.

Comment: The value of capacity has been cached by compiler. I moved RingBuffer implementation from header to .cpp file so now I see function calls in assembly. But I think it is just workaround. I think that maybe volatile could help in this case, but volatile will be deprecaded in c++20, at least most use cases, so I have to find a way to to do this without volatile.

Comment: The obvious answer is to find out which shared variable *does* need to be `atomic<T>`.  `size_t xsize` is a local so it is not the problem, it's just getting the return value of a function.  But that function must read something.  If this doesn't make sense to you, I'd suggest finding a library instead of trying to write your own lock-free code.  Or if you want to learn, find some tutorials on how to write lock-free multi-threaded code using atomic loads/stores (and sometimes RMWs if necessary).  `volatile` is not the right answer, as the first link in my answer explained.

Comment: So you have SendData calls both in the foreground and in the interrupt?  Do I understand that right?

Comment: could be undefined behavior could be a timing thing, I am smelling timing, but you have to dig in.  If you are asking the how do I see the output of the compiler question, good luck.  I would start by asking myself, why would I use an interrupt, you need a serious reason to justify using interrupts, esp with uarts and how they work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually code that only works with optimization disabled is a sign of Undefined Behaviour: the compiler is allowed to make assumptions that you violated.  It doesn't always exploit those assumptions with optimization disabled, e.g. every variable is treated something like `volatile` so strict-aliasing and data race UB are rarely a problem with optimization disabled.  e.g. forgetting to use `atomic<T>` for a shared var usually only causes a problem with optimization, unless you were using an RMW operation like `++`.  [MCU programming - C++ O2 optimization breaks while loop](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/387478)

Obviously compile with full warnings (`-Wall -Wextra`); compile-time-visible UB will often be noticed by the compiler and warned about, especially in cases where it gives up and assumes a code-path is unreachable because it encounters UB, and doesn't even emit a return instruction along that path.

---

**But if you really want the answer to the literal question you asked (what was optimized / optimized away), not the implicit debugging question:**

The only answer to such a generic question is a very generic answer: Compare the compiler's asm output, or the compiler's internal representation of program logic.

Comparing asm text output is hard because one tiny difference in register allocation choice can make every instruction in a whole function use different registers.

So a better bet is probably getting GCC to print out its GIMPLE representation of the code, the form it uses to represent the program for most optimizations.  At some stages it can even dump that back into a C-like form.

e.g. for this example, which I'm not sure demonstrates anything interesting about optimization except that `z` gets optimized away (constant-propagation):

```
int foo(int x) {
    int z = 1;
    int y = x * 2 + z;
    return y;
}
```

with `-O1` from [ARM(none) gcc 8.3.1 on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJNJb0AGTy1MAOWMAjTMRABWUgAdUCwuto9QxMzb19/Ohs7RyMXN08lFTU6BgJmYgIg41NORWVMVQDU9IIoh2dXQQU0jKyQ3OqSspi4rgBKRVQDYmQOAHJbAgBqGlQIQaGADzah8QB2WQAGAEEhtaGJgC9ZgGYAESHOcR2l1fWJgE9dg8mhgCohyVmZIc3j0/Wh4kwCbtohi7vcQreZ7PodVggPruPqkUx9Raw1BQnRyORDBRdHqYZ47TiwghQxFtDoAaxAOx2ADpKbS6fSAGxCKHcWHwxGkZF9WEKECLUiEhHg0hwWBINBGLx4dhkCgQCVSmUgdJGAAceNIVGlBFcvIgTiJsKctnSFyh%2BNIEqMWgIAHlaKwzULSFgjCJgOxDS68N9CgA3TC852YSYFAw682wwbKL2sPBOYimvRYSMC4h4IyRjo0ehMNgcHj8QTCUQoNEyITx3mQDqoLzJWhBgC0totiQKDc02jqOQAnBZtM0Km5eD4/A2e1x%2B2OIrQh7FKrx24UUjVMvpslO8kkimv560l2vJ5x%2B40MvvFx1Md1eu1mdC2V6ucsAEoAWSGwGQyCGqppVM4IYIFoOhMBmCBcEIEhcVyIY9ElaVXBgmZURkOQCUNElSHJSkaXpfDKSZSE%2BlZOEnyhHk%2BQFTCRRgRAQC/ZB0GMLxyEoAB9BVEPTdBBHYzB8CIHjBGYdB0G%2BBQFFtesAlTNhWGkzs%2BgtJxWFQZBSSkmSNGU2EsDSaUtKUi0c0YFhPULPAvGYPYWNTOM7BAxTZN00hEwAd2cnSLQyVhbMlL1lx1dAAAVmEkqE8UkYgqS1Wg2B5fIV1MCBLGPAdrFscoFzcOYwnHAJ0pnBsL1y7cO13Ep0qCyrzyylpKjys912CHJFD3erhxAOYrzjIwvPhNs0gIIyXItAhvkwfyvC9Aw8HQAbUz9OtRu84ViJhMjnWfd9P2/X9/0A4DQJmABxHQdCGAAVSaAHoXyuqwhgANTwTB3KQiDBOgqQNTg1AEJlZCMKFLCcOpAiCPvUj2SRCjFCowViQhKFJEfbb4aR8EOgDYg/A0bggA%3D) (which has a GIMPLE tree viewer) we get this asm output

```
foo(int):
        lsl     r0, r0, #1
        add     r0, r0, #1
        bx      lr
```

This GIMPLE output after optimization pass 232t.optimized:

```
;; Function foo (_Z3fooi, funcdef_no=0, decl_uid=4625, cgraph_uid=0, symbol_order=0)

foo (int x)
{
  int y;
  int _1;

  <bb 2> [local count: 1073741825]:
  # DEBUG BEGIN_STMT
  # DEBUG z => 1
  # DEBUG BEGIN_STMT
  _1 = x_2(D) * 2;
  y_3 = _1 + 1;
  # DEBUG y => y_3
  # DEBUG BEGIN_STMT
  return y_3;

}
```

and this RTL output after optimization pass 312r.final:

```
;; Function foo (_Z3fooi, funcdef_no=0, decl_uid=4625, cgraph_uid=0, symbol_order=0)



foo

Dataflow summary:
;;  invalidated by call      0 [r0] 1 [r1] 2 [r2] 3 [r3] 12 [ip] 14 [lr] 15 [pc] 16 [s0] 17 [s1] 18 [s2] 19 [s3] 20 [s4] 21 [s5] 22 [s6] 23 [s7] 24 [s8] 25 [s9] 26 [s10] 27 [s11] 28 [s12] 29 [s13] 30 [s14] 31 [s15] 32 [s16] 33 [s17] 34 [s18] 35 [s19] 36 [s20] 37 [s21] 38 [s22] 39 [s23] 40 [s24] 41 [s25] 42 [s26] 43 [s27] 44 [s28] 45 [s29] 46 [s30] 47 [s31] 48 [d16] 49 [?16] 50 [d17] 51 [?17] 52 [d18] 53 [?18] 54 [d19] 55 [?19] 56 [d20] 57 [?20] 58 [d21] 59 [?21] 60 [d22] 61 [?22] 62 [d23] 63 [?23] 64 [d24] 65 [?24] 66 [d25] 67 [?25] 68 [d26] 69 [?26] 70 [d27] 71 [?27] 72 [d28] 73 [?28] 74 [d29] 75 [?29] 76 [d30] 77 [?30] 78 [d31] 79 [?31] 80 [wr0] 81 [wr1] 82 [wr2] 83 [wr3] 84 [wr4] 85 [wr5] 86 [wr6] 87 [wr7] 88 [wr8] 89 [wr9] 90 [wr10] 91 [wr11] 92 [wr12] 93 [wr13] 94 [wr14] 95 [wr15] 96 [wcgr0] 97 [wcgr1] 98 [wcgr2] 99 [wcgr3] 100 [cc] 101 [vfpcc]
;;  hardware regs used   13 [sp]
;;  regular block artificial uses    13 [sp]
;;  eh block artificial uses     13 [sp] 103 [afp]
;;  entry block defs     0 [r0] 1 [r1] 2 [r2] 3 [r3] 13 [sp] 14 [lr]
;;  exit block uses      0 [r0] 13 [sp] 14 [lr]
;;  regs ever live   0 [r0]
;;  ref usage   r0={3d,4u} r1={1d} r2={1d} r3={1d} r13={1d,2u} r14={1d,1u} 
;;    total ref usage 15{8d,7u,0e} in 4{4 regular + 0 call} insns.
(note 1 0 28 NOTE_INSN_DELETED)
(note 28 1 4 (var_location x (reg:SI 0 r0 [ x ])) NOTE_INSN_VAR_LOCATION)
(note 4 28 21 [bb 2] NOTE_INSN_BASIC_BLOCK)
(note 21 4 2 NOTE_INSN_PROLOGUE_END)
(note 2 21 3 NOTE_INSN_DELETED)
(note 3 2 25 NOTE_INSN_FUNCTION_BEG)
(note 25 3 29 ./example.cpp:2 NOTE_INSN_BEGIN_STMT)
(note 29 25 26 (var_location z (const_int 1 [0x1])) NOTE_INSN_VAR_LOCATION)
(note 26 29 30 ./example.cpp:3 NOTE_INSN_BEGIN_STMT)
(note 30 26 27 (var_location y (plus:SI (ashift:SI (reg:SI 0 r0 [ x ])
        (const_int 1 [0x1]))
    (const_int 1 [0x1]))) NOTE_INSN_VAR_LOCATION)
(note 27 30 11 ./example.cpp:4 NOTE_INSN_BEGIN_STMT)
(insn 11 27 31 (set (reg:SI 0 r0 [114])
        (ashift:SI (reg:SI 0 r0 [ x ])
            (const_int 1 [0x1]))) "./example.cpp":3 129 {*arm_shiftsi3}
     (nil))
(note 31 11 32 (var_location y (plus:SI (ashift:SI (entry_value:SI (reg:SI 0 r0 [ x ]))
        (const_int 1 [0x1]))
    (const_int 1 [0x1]))) NOTE_INSN_VAR_LOCATION)
(note 32 31 12 (var_location x (entry_value:SI (reg:SI 0 r0 [ x ]))) NOTE_INSN_VAR_LOCATION)
(note 12 32 17 NOTE_INSN_DELETED)
(insn 17 12 33 (set (reg/i:SI 0 r0)
        (plus:SI (reg:SI 0 r0 [114])
            (const_int 1 [0x1]))) "./example.cpp":5 4 {*arm_addsi3}
     (nil))
(note 33 17 18 (var_location y (reg/i:SI 0 r0)) NOTE_INSN_VAR_LOCATION)
(insn 18 33 22 (use (reg/i:SI 0 r0)) "./example.cpp":5 -1
     (nil))
(note 22 18 23 NOTE_INSN_EPILOGUE_BEG)
(jump_insn 23 22 24 (return) "./example.cpp":5 220 {*arm_return}
     (nil)
 -> return)
(barrier 24 23 20)
(note 20 24 0 NOTE_INSN_DELETED)
```

If you want to really understand "what GCC optimized away", you'd better brush up on your GIMPLE and/or RTL.  (GCC internals manual:  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html)

I'm not going to clutter the answer with the GIMPLE and RTL outputs for `-O0`, but you can (I think) set up 2 compiler panes on Godbolt so you can diff them.

Comment: Thank for your detailed answer! I changed variable type from size_t to std::atomic<size_t> and now it works even with -Os. I also updated question, so you can find some details.

Comment: `size_t xsize` is a local whose address isn't taken, so clearly it's not a shared variable and doesn't need to be `atomic<size_t>` because it's not directly being accessed by multiple threads or interrupt handlers.  Your change just hid your bug for some reason, perhaps by making stores and loads slower and maybe making some race condition not happen, or because it limited optimization of surrounding code.  The point of this answer was *not* to randomly change things to `atomic<T>`.  You should assume your code is still buggy and can still break at any time for any unrelated change.

Comment: @bielu000: Post a different question if you want to ask a specific debugging question about your actual code.  Of course you'll need to reduce it to a [mcve] to make it appropriate for Stack Overflow.  Very few people are interested in debugging your full project for you.  And posting hard-to-read *images* of disassembly is not helpful, especially when the source is hidden behind off-site links that could rot in future.  Your edit made the question a worse Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. So I will continue investigation.